# commutative ring with no zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Question from chapter on 'Integral Domains' from Gallian .which said an integral domain does not contains zero-divisor and is a commutative ring.

Does there exist any other commutative ring which is not a integral domain  and also does not contain zero-divisor...

Comment: Does the definition of a ring in Gallian require a multiplicative identity? It seems this makes a difference.

Comment: @MattPressland in the book ring does not requires to have a multiplicative identity..

Comment: OK - for completeness and future reference, because lots of people use lots of different definitions, it might be good to say this in the question, and to say whether or not an integral domain is required to have an identity.

Comment: This question is very enlightening. I learned that definitions have not been standardized apparently. Perhaps NIST should get involved. It can be quite confusing. Wikipedia says one thing, my book says another, etc, etc.

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer:** In this answer, the definition of a ring requires a multiplicative identity. If you use another definition of ring that does not make this requirement, then you might get a different answer - indeed, other people have provided such different answers.

We know that an integral domain doesn't contain (non-zero) zero-divisors because that (as well as the ring being non-zero itself) is the definition of an integral domain! So apart from the vacuous example of the zero ring, which has no non-zero zero-divisors but is not an integral domain by definition, there are no examples.

Comment: It depends on your definition of integral domain, for me integral domains may be non-unital, but for others not (see answer below).

Comment: @CSA I should have guessed something like this would happen! Thanks for catching, I'll add a disclaimer.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From my understanding, the ring $nZ$ for $n > 0$, with the usual multiplication and division, counts as a commutative ring without zero divisors but is not an integral domain because it doesn't contain unity (aka, multiplicative identity). I think your question stems from not noting that an integral domain is distinguished by containing unity.

Comment: $n\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal and not a ring (unless by ring you mean non-unital ring,but i don't expect that's what he means by ring).

Comment: nZ together with its additive operation qualifies as a group. It multiplicative operation is associative and the left and right distributive laws apply so from my understanding nZ is definitely a commutative ring.

Comment: Then what would the unit be? since $nZ$ has the multiplicative structure of $\mathbb{Z}$ (according to your definition) and yet $\mathbb{Z}$'s unit (unique) is $1$, but $1\not\in n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There is no unity. Hence it is a what I believe is a good example of a commutative ring that doesn't contain unity. Not all rings contain unity.

Comment: I will say, the definition of a ring in wikipedia does include unity while the definition in "A First Course in Abstract Algebra 5th edition" does not. In the book, a ring with unity is always qualified as a ring with unity. So I'm a bit confused.

Comment: haha I know that (see my first comment) but i just was expecting (judging by the level of his question) that he most likely was only interested in the category CRings not CRngs :P
(but if he is also considering CRngs then you are perfectly right, and I agree completely :) )

Comment: Here is what wolfram says regarding Rings. (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ring.html) So this clarifies it a bit but wikipedia does serve to obfuscate what I thought I understood.

Comment: I understand your reference now. Point taken. I'm going to be more careful when it comes to these definitions. But it does appear the answer marked correct is actually not an answer.

Comment: Also, it depends on the definition of integral domain, some authors do not require integral domains to be unital (moreover it seems fitting to take that as the definition if we are to consider non-unital examples); so i partially agree with you.

Comment: @TheOldHag my definition of integral domain requires to have a unity...